# Task Compact Layout is not displaying on hover from its related list

Tags: page-layout, related-list, flexipages, compact-layout, mousehover

Normally when we have a related list, when we hover our mouse to the clickable link, it'll display a pop up that will show a quick summary (or set of fields) of a record, as shown below:

[image]

But this doesn't seem to work with the Task related list, even if the compact layout is already set. (Imagine I'm hovering my mouse at one of the "Confirmation Call" link, but it doesn't show any pop up that would show its summary.)

[image]

Currently, I can't find any source that says that this isn't possible for Task. I would like to know if I'm missing any configuration that should be set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per salesforce standard functionality, this feature is not available at this moment. You can upvote for this idea in the below [link](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdjRqUAJ/extend-hovers-to-activity-history)

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to add a Tasks related list to any page layout, but I am able to add a "Open Activities" related list which includes tasks. The pop-up is present on hover of the clickable link. Could you provide more details on this issue?